# Weak instrument problem, how can a "false experiment" serve as an identification check?

Tags: references, econometrics, instrumental-variables, identifiability

In their 2004 paper, Miguel et al. investigate the role of income growth by using current and lagged rainfall as an instrument. However, the instruments are somewhat weak: the joint F-statistic is only 4.5. (Miguel et al., 2004, p.735). To see whether or not this might constitute a problem, they estimate a "false experiment" as an identification check. They add future rainfall growth "which should be orthogonal to current economic growth, conditional on country-specific time trends" (ibid, p.736) as an explanatory variable. The coefficient is indeed close to zero.

I understand the idea of the false experiment: the coefficient of a variable that in reality cannot have an effect should be statistically irrelevant. However, I have trouble understanding the connection between this false experiment and the supposed relevance of the instrument. Can anyone provide an explanation or a suggestion for further reading?

- Miguel, Edward, Shanker Satyanath and Ernest Sergenti (2004).  ‘Economic Shocks and Civil Conflict: An Instrumental Variables Approach’, Journal of Political Economy, 112(4): 725-753. ([pdf](http://www.nber.org/ens/feldstein/Papers/_Paper__Economic_Shocks_and_Civil_Conflict.pdf))